# Execute correctly async functions at sync functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

```js
const mainTasks = ['mainTask1', 'mainTask2', 'mainTask3', 'mainTask4']
const subTasks = ['subTask1', 'subTask2', 'subTask3']
const defaultTimeout = 1000

// SubTasks should be run as async
// Tasks should be run as sync

const subTaskHandler = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, defaultTimeout * 2);
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    await Promise.all(
        mainTasks.map((mainTask, index) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    for (subTask of subTasks) {
                        await subTaskHandler(defaultTimeout)
                        console.log(`${mainTask} -> ${subTask}: Completed`)
                    }
                    resolve()
                }, defaultTimeout + index * 1000)
            })

        })
    )
    console.log('done')
}

main()
```

I'm going to execute **mainTasks** as sync and **subTasks** as async
At the end, I try catch the point when the **mainTasks** are all finished as well **subTasks**.
Seems I got the point But I met the unexpected result.

```
mainTask1 -> subTask1: Completed
mainTask2 -> subTask1: Completed
mainTask3 -> subTask2: Completed
mainTask1 -> subTask2: Completed
mainTask4 -> subTask3: Completed
mainTask2 -> subTask2: Completed
mainTask3 -> subTask3: Completed
mainTask1 -> subTask3: Completed
mainTask4 -> subTask3: Completed
mainTask2 -> subTask3: Completed
mainTask3 -> subTask3: Completed
mainTask4 -> subTask3: Completed
done
```

Where is **mainTask4 -> subTask1** and 2??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your

```
for (subTask of subTasks) {
```

You forgot to declare the `subTask` variable, so it's implicitly global - it doesn't have block scope. It gets reassigned on every iteration *and* on every maintask. So, after the asynchronous `await` inside the `for`:

```
                for (subTask of subTasks) {
                    await subTaskHandler(defaultTimeout)
                    console.log(`${mainTask} -> ${subTask}: Completed`)
                }
```

By the time any of the `await`s resolve, the `subTask` variable will hold the value assigned to it during the *most recently initialized subtask* (rather than the variable assigned to it during the current subtask).

Change to:

```
for (const subTask of subTasks) {
```

and it'll work as expected.

```js
const mainTasks = ['mainTask1', 'mainTask2', 'mainTask3', 'mainTask4']
const subTasks = ['subTask1', 'subTask2', 'subTask3']
const defaultTimeout = 1000

// SubTasks should be run as async
// Tasks should be run as sync

const subTaskHandler = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, defaultTimeout * 2);
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    await Promise.all(
        mainTasks.map((mainTask, index) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    for (const subTask of subTasks) {
                        await subTaskHandler(defaultTimeout)
                        console.log(`${mainTask} -> ${subTask}: Completed`)
                    }
                    resolve()
                }, defaultTimeout + index * 1000)
            })

        })
    )
    console.log('done')
}

main()
```

You could also consider using strict mode and/or a linter, to catch these errors earlier:

```js
'use strict';

const mainTasks = ['mainTask1', 'mainTask2', 'mainTask3', 'mainTask4']
const subTasks = ['subTask1', 'subTask2', 'subTask3']
const defaultTimeout = 1000

// SubTasks should be run as async
// Tasks should be run as sync

const subTaskHandler = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, defaultTimeout * 2);
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    await Promise.all(
        mainTasks.map((mainTask, index) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    for (subTask of subTasks) {
                        await subTaskHandler(defaultTimeout)
                        console.log(`${mainTask} -> ${subTask}: Completed`)
                    }
                    resolve()
                }, defaultTimeout + index * 1000)
            })

        })
    )
    console.log('done')
}

main()
```

> Error: Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: subTask is not defined

Comment: thats why you `"use strict";`